# Openerp or odoo use ajax to send POST and GET data ? without refreshing

Tags: ajax, post, get, odoo

I want to know the technology used in ODOO(Openerp) to send POST and GET data without refreshing  the page: because I don't see any AJAX code !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odoo is using http POST/GET requests to update the user interface. A combination of javascript making requests on the page and controllers responding. Odoo also uses longpolling to allow the server to provide updates to the client.

Take a look at the web addon

Of particular note would be

`addons/web/controllers/main.py`
and
`addons/web/static/src/js`

The js directory mentioned above (i am sorry there is a lot there). Defines how the standard ui widgets work (and much more). Most of the files are reasonably named to give you an indication of what is going on in each file.

You will also want to look at the framework directory within the above noted directory.

There you will find `ajax.js` which (you guessed it!) is the Odoo ajax module.

NOTE: The above directories are similar in Odoo8 however Odoo9 and Odoo10 have the above structure. Odoo8 does not have an ajax.js (to my knowledge) .

Comment: Thank you very much PHILIP, your answer has explained what I want.